# Get all users who is not friend with login user

Tags: php, mysql

i have a little problem with MySql query. I have two tables:

```
Table name "users"
id, profilephoto, sex, name, lastname

Table name "friends"
id, idSender, idReceiver
```

idSender and idReceiver is value of id users who send friend request, and who get friend request.
Now i need get all users who is not friend with some login user (for example - User ID - 12)

I make this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.profilephoto,users.sex,users.name,users.lastname FROM users INNER JOIN friends ON users.id=friends.idSender WHERE (friends.idSender!=12 OR friends.idReceiver!=12)
```

And I get wrong informations.

If someone have any idea, I will be thankful.

Simple data from table>
Table Users:
id | profilephoto | sex | name | lastname
1 | image1.jpg | 1 | John | Snow
2 | image2.jpg | 2 | Lisa | Test
3 | image3.jpg | 1 | Patric | Test
4 | image4.jpg | 2 | Elizabet | Test

Table friends:
id | idReceiver | idSender
1 | 1 | 2   // Lisa send friend request to John
2 | 2 | 3   // Patric send friend request to Lisa
For Lisa I want to display only Elizabet
For Elizabet I want to display Lisa, John and Patric
For John I need Patric and Elizabet
For Patric I need John and Elizabet

Comment: Can you show some sample data from your two tables, and show which users should be selected and which should not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make left join

```
SELECT * from users u 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.idSender OR u.id = f.idReceiver
WHERE u.id = 12 
AND f.idSender IS NULL 
OR f.idReciever IS NULL
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying this query will select user has no friends

```
select  u.* 
from user u
left join friends f on f.idSender= u.id or f.idReceiver= u.id
where f.id is null
```